# the Button moves up when keyboard appears

Tags: android

Here I'm trying to add a medicine from the AutoCompleteTextView's suggestion into the RecyclerView

[image]

After choosing the medicine then click the green add icon

[image]

[then the button moves up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d114i.jpg)

I tried to put

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` ,
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

*also tried* `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

into my `AndroidManifest` but it didn't work. any help? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What triggers the button Sign Up button up? When you click on the plus button?

Comment: yes, when I clicked plus button the Signup button just appear above the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```